# MSSQL Order by date with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have this query segment below where I'm trying to build a string of "month-year" from a date field in this table. It's very important that it comes in the right order starting from current month going forward 12 months.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(char(3), StartDate, 0) + '-' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(StartDate)), 2) AS y 
      FROM Products2
     ) AS Y
--ORDER BY y desc
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'')
```

This query isn't pulling the dates in the right order and I wanted to see if you guys know of any neat tricks to pull the dates in the correct order. I can bring in the startDate column and sort it by that but it brings in duplicates as it may have several entries for the same month. I've created a sample table here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a500/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you could use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

;WITH cte AS       -- get only one date per month/year
(
  SELECT MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate
  FROM #Products2 
  GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate)
)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(StartDate, 'MMM-yy'))
                      FROM cte
                      ORDER BY StartDate      
                      FOR XML PATH('')),
                    1, 1, N'');

SELECT @cols;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417394)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                                        result                                                        ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [Dec-15],[Jan-16],[Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16],[May-16],[Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16],[Dec-16] ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
                      FROM   (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), StartDate, 0) + '-'
                                     + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(StartDate)), 2) AS y,
                                     MIN(StartDate)                                AS z
                              FROM   Products2
                              GROUP  BY CONVERT(CHAR(3), StartDate, 0) + '-'
                                        + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(StartDate)), 2)) AS Y
                      ORDER  BY z
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, N'');

SELECT @cols;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a500/25)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just getting the month/year so we can truncate to the first day of the month and include that in the query.

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, StartDate), 0)  monthStart
```

Now we can order by it:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


 SELECT @cols = STUFF(
  (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(char(3), StartDate, 0) + '-' +  
        RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(StartDate)), 2) AS y, 
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, StartDate), 0)  monthStart
        FROM Products2
       ) AS Y
  ORDER BY monthStart
  FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

select @cols;
```

This is the output:

> [Dec-15],[Jan-16],[Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16],[May-16],[Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16],[Dec-16]

Is that what you are looking for?  Here is a fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a500/67

Better yet, just select the distinct month start dates and then only do the string conversion on that.

```
   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

     SELECT @cols = STUFF(
      (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(3), monthStart, 0) + '-' +  
            RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(monthStart)), 2)) AS [text()]
      FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, StartDate), 0)  monthStart
      FROM Products2
           ) AS Y
      ORDER BY monthStart
      FOR XML PATH('')),
    1, 1, N'');

    select @cols;
```

Here is that fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a500/72

Comment: I think the second solution above is the best solution as there is less string conversion.  You get the distinct rows before the conversion.  It is better than the choice above with string conversion in the group by and the select statement.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.